# Drawing Loops in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need your kind help to convert this image in TikZ/PGF, if possible:

[image]

FYI , I want to use the image on a `beamerslide` and a standard `article` type document (A4 paper).

I used Inkscape (`.svg > .png`), which does the job OK. But it doesn't provide any `TikZ` code - instead give `PSTricks` type code, which is even more confusing to me. Is there any GUI for `TikZ/PGF`?

Comment: Please show some attempt you've made in achieving this and specify what you're struggling with. The point of this Q&A site is to solve specific problems, not to have other people do your work. If your actual question is _Is there any GUI for TikZ/PGF?_, then clearly state so. If you're looking for someone to transfer your image to TikZ, you've come to the wrong place, sorry.

Comment: You can use a tree structure [such as this one](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/). You can test your code by using QTikZ on the fly for more convenience.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to do this in TikZ? For example, there are dedicated packages for drawing pseudocode algorithms. For example, `algorithm2e`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fairly easy, see code below. Instead of writing the `loop` letters below each other, I rotated the node.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% putting the nodes

\node[red,right] (1) at (0,0) {first guess};
\node[black,right] (2) at (2,-2) {second guess};
\node[blue,right] (3) at (4,-4) {third guess};

% drawing arrows; the scopes library is used for putting the arrow tip option [-latex} only once; the |- notation means: from first point go straight down and then right to the second point, try -| to see the difference

{[-latex]
    \draw[red] (1.south) |- (2.west);
    \draw[black] (2.south) |- (3.west);
    \draw[red] (1.220) -- node[rotate=-90, below] {loop} ++(0,-12) -- ++(6,0) node[right] {End};
    \draw[black] (2.220) -- node[rotate=-90, below] {loop} ++(0,-8) -- ++(4,0) node[right] {End};
    \draw[blue] (3.220) -- node[rotate=-90, below] {loop} node[right] {Max} ++(0,-4) -- ++(2,0) node[right] {End};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** If I get you right, you want

```
\draw[red] (1.south) -- (0,-2) -- (2.west);
\draw[black] (2.south) -- (2,-4) -- (3.west);
```

which yields the same result as before.

---

**Edit 2:** If one uses `text width=3cm` to break text inside the nodes, one alters the height of the node and for that also the coordinates of the `220` degree nodes. So I used the calc library to compute the coordinates relative to the node's centers. That way the arrows remain equally spaced and terminate at the same coordinates. The following picture illustrates the problem:

[image]

And the cleaned up code solving the problem with the calc library:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% putting the nodes

\node[red] (1) at (0,0) {first guess};
\node[black] (2) at (2,-2) {second guess};
\node[blue,text width=3cm] (3) at (4,-4) {Take a guess on $l(n)$ while Shanananana};

% drawing arrows; the scopes library is used for putting the arrow tip option [-latex} only once;
% the |- notation means: from first point go straight down and then right to the second point,
% try -| to see the difference

{[-latex,very thick]
    \draw[red] (1.south) -- (0,-2) -- (2.west);
    \draw[black] (2.south) -- (2,-4) -- (3.west);
    \draw[red] ($(1.south) + (-0.4,0)$) --  node[rotate=-90, below] {loop} ($(1.center) + (-0.4,-12)$)  -- ++(6,0) node[right] {End};
    \draw[black] ($(2.south) + (-0.4,0)$) -- node[rotate=-90, below] {loop} ($(2.center) + (-0.4,-8)$) -- ++(4,0) node[right] {End};
    \draw[blue] ($(3.south) + (-0.4,0)$) -- node[rotate=-90, below] {loop} node[right] {Max} ($(3.center) + (-0.4,-4)$) -- +(2,0) node[right] {End};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the final result. Note that you can add a `text width` to the other nodes as well, the arrows still remain correct:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. After adding all the usual texts, I'm getting two arrows in the opposite direction. Could you please tell me which I should tweak.   Also, how can I break those "take a guess ..." line into two smaller lines as in the image (of the 1st post). I tried using ` \\ ` before `while`, which gives error.

Comment: Could you please post the code that's making trouble?

Comment: You can break lines by specifying a `text width=Xcm` but this influences the position of the `220` degree anchor. I'm working on a work around. Although it still works, the ''End'' nodes are then no longer aligned, which I don't like ;)

Answer (score 6):

You have already drawn this diagram in Inkscape right?. Then visit  [this site](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) and install inkscape2tikz. Using this you can export tikz code without any trouble.

If you are in search of any Gui, then try [QTikz](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) or [TikzEdt](http://code.google.com/p/tikzedt/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before, but the script is probably not meant to be used when we're using Glyphs (in Incscape) for those math and Greek symbols.

Comment: For adding math and things like that you can install TexText extension from the same website and then you can type re-editable LaTeX commands.